# Linux/mysql writing mysql table output to a file AND keeping mysql formatting.

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line, output

I am using a command like the one below in mysql. And when it displays the table data it is formatted in a very clean table with even spacing and | as column separators.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

When I run the command from a CLI, like bellow, the output is nice and clean just as if i was running it from within mysql.

```
$ mysql -e "USE databse_name;" -e "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME;"
```

HOWEVER, if i tell the CLI command to write the output of the same command to a file (see the command bellow) I loose all of that nice formatting and the file that is written ends up looking terrible.

```
$ mysql -e "USE databse_name;" -e "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME;" > ~/tablename.txt
```

Does any one know how to fix this?
Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the mysql CLI and write there

```
tee ~/tablename.txt
```

And than write your query, output of all queries will be collected into file ~/tablename.txt.
When query executed write in console

```
notee
```

Comment: @DavidMcAninch: Should add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Add the -t option.

```
mysql database_name -t -e "SELECT * FROM table_name" > ~/tablename.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from control_pagos
into outfile 'c:\\data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```